# Получить массив vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Получаю данные через axios

```
  axios.post('api/v2/getinfo', {id : id}).then(response => {
     this.dataObject = response.data.data
  })
```

Если вывести `{{ dataObject.contracts_active }}` получаю

```
   [ [ 
    { "id": "1", "base_id": 1, "name": "Зирка Лева", "start": "23.05.2019", "end": "23.05.20", "end_actually": "23.05.20", "active": 1 },
     { "id": "5", "base_id": 1, "name": "Зирка Лева2", "start": "23.05.2019", "end": "23.05.20", "end_actually": "23.05.20", "active": 1 }
    ] ]
```

Вопрос как получить массив не обвернутый в 2 пары скобок [ ], то есть изменить или получить

```
   [  
    { "id": "1", "base_id": 1, "name": "Зирка Лева", "start": "23.05.2019", "end": "23.05.20", "end_actually": "23.05.20", "active": 1 },
     { "id": "5", "base_id": 1, "name": "Зирка Лева2", "start": "23.05.2019", "end": "23.05.20", "end_actually": "23.05.20", "active": 1 }
    ]
```

Comment: для начала посмотреть в инструментах разработчика в браузере на ответ по этому запросу на вкладке Network (Сеть)

Comment: это и приходит в ответе

Comment: Что же вы тогда хотите от Vue или axios? Либо возвращайте с сервера не массив массивов, а только вложенный, либо берите нулевой элемент массива на клиенте. А если вам придет два массива в этом корневом массиве? Какой будете выбирать?